# wxStaticBitmap constructor takes wxGDIImage instead of wxBitmap

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitmap, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I'm trying to create a static bitmap but the constructor only accepts wxGDIImages. 
Here is the code from the FormBuilder:

```
wxStaticBitmap* tmtBitmap = new wxStaticBitmap( this, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap( wxT("directory"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
```

Is there any way to convert the wxBitmap to a wxGDIImage? Or create a wxGDIImage given the directory?

Maybe there is another way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: `wxBitmap` IS A `wxGDIImage` (which is an internal class in wxWidgets that you shouldn't really need to care about) so whichever problem you had wasn't related to this, please always include (abbreviated, if necessary) error message when asking about compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wxStaticBitmap` does accept `wxBitmap` in its constructor ([wx API-Doc](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxstaticbitmap.html#wxstaticbitmapconstr))
The error message produced by the compiler might be a bit misleading
im guessing you see something like this:

```
include/wx/msw/statbmp.h:80: note: candidates are: wxStaticBitmap::wxStaticBitmap(const wxStaticBitmap&)
include/wx/msw/statbmp.h:34: note:                 wxStaticBitmap::wxStaticBitmap(wxWindow*, wxWindowID, const wxGDIImage&, const wxPoint&, const wxSize&, long int, const wxString&)
include/wx/msw/statbmp.h:25: note:                 wxStaticBitmap::wxStaticBitmap()
```

Since it is the only thing context depending, there seems to be a problem with your `this` pointer, either you are not "inside" a `wxWindow`
 or your compiler can't figure out the static type. You can use something like this to verify: (don't do that in productive code)

```
wxStaticBitmap* tmtBitmap = new wxStaticBitmap( (wxWindow*)NULL, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap( wxT("directory"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
```

or

```
wxStaticBitmap* tmtBitmap = new wxStaticBitmap( (wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap( wxT("directory"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
```

Comment: You're right, I was carelessly copying over code from the wxFormBuilder. 'this' was not a wxWindow. Thanks.

Comment: Don't create `wxStaticBitmap` with `NULL` parent, a child window must have a valid parent. And, of course, don't cast a non-window to `wxWindow`, this will simply crash.

Comment: Maybe i should have been a bit more specific, of course using "Null-Parents" or just casting to `wxWindow *` is not a good idea in general. This was just meant for verification of the compiler output